# Unity 2D. Why raycasting does not work properly?

Tags: unity-game-engine, raycasting

With this code I am changing color of gun object if raycast can hit player. Color changes as soon as Player walks into raycast radius. However color won't switch back from red to green as soon as player either goes away (more than Range distance) or hide behind walls. It will eventually switch back to green but not right away. Can you please help me figure out what seems to be the problem?

```
void Update()
    {
        Vector2 targetPos = Target.position;
        Direction = targetPos - (Vector2)transform.position;
        RaycastHit2D rayInfo = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Direction, Range, layerMask);
        if (rayInfo)
        {
            if (rayInfo.collider.gameObject.tag == "Player")
            {
                if (Detected == false)
                {
                    Detected = true;
                    Gun.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.red;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (Detected == true)
                {
                    Detected = false;
                    Gun.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.green;

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there any other code that makes changes to Detected?

Answer (score 0):

When your raycasthit doesn't hit anything with specified LayerMask you don't change your gun's color maybe this is the issue. if your reset your gun color it can solve. Here is the example

```cs
//define gunColor variable it is default color of your gun
Color gunColor=Color.green;

void Update()
{
    Vector2 targetPos = Target.position;
    Direction = targetPos - (Vector2)transform.position;
    RaycastHit2D rayInfo = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Direction, Range, layerMask);

    if (rayInfo)
    {

        gunColor=rayInfo.collider.gameObject.CompareTag("Player")?Color.red:Color.green,

    }else{
      //when raycasthit doesnt hit any thing set gun color to green;
      gunColor=Color.green;
    }
    //update gun color
    Gun.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = gunColor;
}
```

Comment: Nope, it does not help.
When my player gets detected enemy glows red and tries to shoot me. When I run away from him or hide behind wall (that does not let raycast hit my player) enemy is still triggered. Maybe issue is with how i update rayinfo code?